# Cancel a Google Maps V3 InfoWindow close event when the user hovers over the InfoWindow

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I want to close infowindow when user mouse out infowindow. However, in the below code even if i put my mouse on infowindow, it closes in 5 secs. Is this bug or there is another solution for that?

```
var info = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: '<div>Loading...</div>'
});



var bindMarker = function(marker, attr, feature)
{   

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function(clicked) {
            info.setContent(self.createInfoWindowFor(marker, attr, feature));
            info.open(self.map, marker);
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', function(){
        setTimeout(function(){info.close(self.map, marker);}, '5000');
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(clicked) {
            info.close(self.map, marker);

    });

};
```

Comment: If i remove setTimeout, it is immediately closed. Nothing changed. I just want to close it in 5 secs. But even if I mouse over on infowindow, it is closed.

Comment: doesn't work. Still infowindow is closed even if I mouse over on it.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your description of the problem. Could you post a jsFiddle?

Comment: In the above code, when I hover on marker, it opens a infowindow. I want to close infowindow when I mouseout of marker. This is good. But while I am holding my mouse on infowindow, it still closes it . I don't want that. I want to keep it open while I am holding my mouse on info window.

Comment: If you want something to happen on mouseover of the infowindow, you need to add an event to do that.  Currently you have mouseover and mouseout events on the marker only (note that there is now Google Maps specific mouse events for the InfoWindow, use normal HTML events).  Also, FYI, the close method on the [InfoWindow](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#InfoWindow) doesn't take any arguments.

Comment: similar question: [gmap.js MouseOver event on an overlay? Is it possible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24641958/gmap-js-mouseover-event-on-an-overlay-is-it-possible/24642666#24642666)

Comment: @snnlankrdsm Can you please share how you did manage to solve this scenario? I am also looking for a solution

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you are using the setTimeOut to have time to put the mouse over the infowindow, so it doesn't close on mouseout of the marker.

Intead of using mouseout of the marker try mousemove of the map. In this way if you put the mouse over the infowindow the event mousemove doesn't fire and can put the mouse over the infowindow whithout closing it. But when you move over the map, the infowindow will close.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'mousemove', function (event) {
    infowindow1.close();
});
```

Comment: Interesting approach, the only potential issue is that with multiple markers on screen they all stay open until you mouse out of the map.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, your code is working fine, you just want to stop the infowindow from disappearing if you mouseover the infowindow.

To do this, you need to create a global variable for the *Timeout ID* (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.clearTimeout) for the timeout function, so in the top of your code:

```
var infoTimeoutID = null;
```

Then you need to set the Timeout ID when you call `setTimeout` like this:

```
        infoTimeoutID = setTimeout(function(){info.close(self.map, marker);}, '5000');
```

Then you want to add a `mouseover` listener to your infoWindow when it is displayed that looks something like this:

```
function() {
    if(infoTimoutId != null) {
        window.clearTimeout(infoTimeoutID);
    }
}
```

You'll also need to add a `mouseout` handler that closes the infoWindow (if desired).