# Gmaps.js - how to add 'pointers' to overlays and make them clickable?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am using GMaps.js to show multiple overlays on one map (similar to AirBNB's maps). I am quite new to Javascript and the GMaps API so am having difficulties with the 2 following issues:

1. I can define custom styled overlays, but when they appear on screen they are missing the ‘pointer’ (aka the little triangle bit at the bottom of the rectangle), instead they just show up as plain rectangles. How can I add these ‘triangles’?
2. I would like the overlays to be clickable. I’ve had a look and it seems the solution is to addListener, but all the examples I’ve seen are where there is only one marker (not multiple like in this case) and also none of the examples used GMaps.js. What's the best way to do this?

My code below. Thanks a lot!

```
<script>
// I've included the Gmaps API and gmaps.js here
jQuery(function($) {
map = new GMaps({
        div: '#map',
        lat: -23.873209,
        lng: 201.155845,
        zoom: 12,
    });

// the Body contains multiple event_location elements which have data-lat and data-lng defined for each event by PHP, which is used below - this part is not a problem
$('.event_location').each(function() {
        map.drawOverlay({
            lat: $(this).attr('data-lat'),
            lng: $(this).attr('data-lng'),
            content: "<div class='map_overlay' style='background-color: blue;'><a href='" + $(this).attr('data-url') + "'>" + $(this).attr('data-subject') + "</a></div>"
        });
    });

});

</script>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24641958/gmap-js-mouseover-event-on-an-overlay-is-it-possible has a good solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For #1, you are missing this part:

```
<div class='overlay_arrow above'></div>
```

From [the example in the documentation](https://hpneo.github.io/gmaps/examples/overlays.html)

**code snippet:**

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  map = new GMaps({
    div: '#map',
    lat: -23.873209,
    lng: 201.155845,
    zoom: 3, //12,
  });

  // the Body contains multiple event_location elements which have data-lat and data-lng defined for each event by PHP, which is used below - this part is not a problem
  $('.event_location').each(function() {
    map.drawOverlay({
      lat: $(this).attr('data-lat'),
      lng: $(this).attr('data-lng'),
      content: "<div class='overlay'><a href='" + $(this).attr('data-url') + "'>" + $(this).attr('data-subject') + "</a><div class='overlay_arrow above'></div></div>"
    });
  });

});
```

```css
body,
html,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  font-family: 'Droid Sans', 'Helvetica', Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 5px;
}
#body {
  width: 1000px;
}
#instructions {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
#instructions li {
  display: none;
}
.overlay {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 60px;
  line-height: 80px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  background: #4477aa;
  border: solid 3px #336699;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px #333;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #666;
  padding: 0 4px;
}
.overlay_arrow {
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -16px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
.overlay_arrow.above {
  bottom: -15px;
  border-left: 16px solid transparent;
  border-right: 16px solid transparent;
  border-top: 16px solid #336699;
}
.overlay_arrow.below {
  top: -15px;
  border-left: 16px solid transparent;
  border-right: 16px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 16px solid #336699;
}
.row {
  font-size: 14px;
}
pre {
  font-family: 'Ubuntu Mono';
  font-size: 14px;
}
.row {
  zoom: 1;
  margin-left: -20px;
}
.row:before,
.row:after {
  display: table;
  content: "";
  zoom: 1;
}
.row:after {
  clear: both;
}
.row>[class*="span"] {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
.span1 {
  width: 40px;
}
.span2 {
  width: 100px;
}
.span3 {
  width: 160px;
}
.span4 {
  width: 220px;
}
.span5 {
  width: 280px;
}
.span6 {
  width: 340px;
}
.span7 {
  width: 400px;
}
.span8 {
  width: 460px;
}
.span9 {
  width: 520px;
}
.span10 {
  width: 580px;
}
.span11 {
  width: 640px;
}
.span12 {
  width: 700px;
}
.span13 {
  width: 760px;
}
.span14 {
  width: 820px;
}
.span15 {
  width: 880px;
}
.span16 {
  width: 940px;
}
.span17 {
  width: 1000px;
}
.span18 {
  width: 1060px;
}
.span19 {
  width: 1120px;
}
.span20 {
  width: 1180px;
}
.span21 {
  width: 1240px;
}
.span22 {
  width: 1300px;
}
.span23 {
  width: 1360px;
}
.span24 {
  width: 1420px;
}
pre.prettyprint {
  background: #fff;
  border-color: #c1c1c1;
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
  -moz-border-radius: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #999;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #999;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #999;
  padding: 5px;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
.label {
  font-size: 10.998px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 14px;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  background-color: #999999;
  margin: 2px 6px;
}
.label {
  padding: 1px 4px 2px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
.notice {
  background-color: #3a87ad;
}
form input[type=text] {
  border: solid 1px #999999;
  padding: 2px;
}
.edit_marker {
  width: 250px;
  height: 80px;
}
.edit_marker p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gmaps.js/0.4.12/gmaps.min.js"></script>

<div id="map"></div>
<div class="event_location" data-lat="-23.873209" data-lng="201.155845" data-subject="something" data-url="http://www.google.com"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, yes that answers question #1